# Error usando strcat, con punteros

Tags: c, concatenación

Objetivo obtener cadena ***p1= "Pedro Cortez"** usando `strcpy` en `C`. El error está al ejecutar F10 y no cuando Compilo con F9

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {

char *puntero1 = "Pedro";
char *puntero2 = "Cortez";

strcat(puntero1," ");
strcat(puntero1,puntero2);
printf("%s",puntero1);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El error de ejecución es porqué en tiempo de ejecución se está tratando de modificar el búfer donde esté guardado la cadena "Pedro" y esto se debe porqué este búfer es solo de lectura, es decir, no lo puedes sobreescribir y la función strcat si lo está haciendo.
Para poder entender el motivo verdadero del error, he creado una posible implementación de la función strcat:

```
void strcatEx(char* const _buf, const char* const _buf2)
{
    int i;
    size_t len = strlen(_buf); 
    size_t len2 = strlen(_buf2) + 1;
    for(i = 0; i != len2; ++i)
    {
        _buf[len++] = _buf2[i];
    }
}
```

Vamos a suponer las direcciones de memoria de la cadena "Pedro" y "Cortez".

```
0x00    0x01    0x02    0x03    0x04    0x05
P        e       d       r       o       \0

0x07    0x08    0x9     0x10    0x11    0x12    0x13
C        o       r       t       e       z       \0
```

"puntero1" tiene guardado la dirección 0x00 y "puntero2" la dirección 0x07.
Entonces vamos a ejecutar paso a paso ese código.
Al momento de llamar nuestra función personalizada strcatEx, quedaría así:

```
strcatEx(puntero1, " ");
```

1. La función se ejecuta y se guarda en la variable "len"  la longitud de la cadena "Pedro" que es 5.
2. El bucle for se ejecuta para realizar la concatenación, pero aquí está el problema:

```
_buf[len++] = _buf2[i];
```

Cuando i valga 0 y len 5. Estaríamos sobrescribiendo la dirección 0x05 (en esta dirección está almacenado el caracter nulo) del búfer donde esté "Pedro" y se supone que solo es de modo lectura. Por esa razón tu programa deja de funcionar.
La solución a tu problema, es usar un arreglo de caracteres, por ejemplo:

```
int main(void)
{

    char name1[13] = "Pedro ";
    char name2[7] = "Cortez";
    strcat(name1, name2);
    printf("%s, %s \n", name1, name2);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo, usar la función estándar strcat no es recomendable, porqué no detecta buffer overflow.
Por ejemplo:
Si tenemos el siguiente código:

```
int main(void)
{

    char name1[13] = "Pedro ";
    char name2[15] = "Cortez Ramirez";
    strcat(name1, name2);
    printf("%s, %s \n", name1, name2);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

La cadena name2 tiene como longitud: 14 caracteres, pero como quiero concatenarlo en name1, no habrá espacio suficiente.
¿Por que? Porqué la longitud de name1 es 6 y de name2 14. 14 + 6 = 20. Entre name1 y name2 hay 20 caracteres, se sobrepasa del tamaño de name1.
Una posible solución es crear tu propia función strcat. Por ejemplo, la función strcatEx, la podemos mejorar de esta manera:

```
unsigned char strcatEx(char* const _buf, const size_t tam, const char* const _buf2)
{
    int i;
    size_t len = strlen(_buf);
    size_t len2 = strlen(_buf2);
    if(len + len2 > tam)
    {
        printf("Error: Posible buffer overflow\n");
        return 0;
    }
    ++len2;
    for(i = 0; i != len2; ++i)
    {
        _buf[len++] = _buf2[i];
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Para llamar la función personalizada strcatEx, lo haces de la siguiente manera:

```
int main(void)
{

    char name1[13] = "Pedro ";
    char name2[7] = "Cortez";
    strcatEx(name1, 13, name2);
    printf("%s, %s \n", name1, name2);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero en estos casos es leer [la documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) (el resaltado es mío):

> #### `strcat`
>
> Definido en la cabecera `<string.h>`
>
> ```
> char *strcat( char *dest, const char *src );
> ```
>
> Anexa una copia de la cadena de bytes terminada en nulo apuntada por `src` al final de la cadena de bytes terminada en nulo apuntada por `dest`. El carácter `src[0]` reemplaza la terminación nula al final de `dest`. A la cadena de bytes resultante se le añadirá la terminación nula. **El comportamiento es indefinido si la formación de destino no es suficientemente extensa como para albergar los contenidos de `src`, `dest` y el carácter nulo**. El comportamiento es indefinido si `dest` o `src` se superponen o si `src` no es cadena de bytes terminada en nulo.

Así pues, en tu primera llamada a `strcat`:

```
strcat(puntero1," ");
```

Estás añadiendo al final de `puntero1` (una cadena de bytes terminada en nulo cuyo contenido es `"Pedro"` y cuya longitud es 6: cinco letras y el carácter nulo) la cadena `" "` (una cadena de bytes terminada en nulo cuya longitud es 2: un espacio y el carácter nulo).

Esto significa que `puntero1` debe tener la capacidad de albergar 7 caracteres (cinco letras, un espacio y el carácter nulo). El problema es que `puntero1` no puede albergar esos caracteres porque su capacidad es 6, no 7. Intenta esto:

```
char puntero1[13] = "Pedro";
char *puntero2 = "Cortez";

strcat(puntero1," ");
strcat(puntero1,puntero2);
printf("%s",puntero1);
```

Si a `puntero1` le das capacidad suficiente para albergar todo lo que quieres concatenar: [no tendrás problema alguno](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9IYZv7V0djmOT9m7).